# Sphinx search results page not showing subsections

Tags: full-text-search, python-sphinx

I am using the Sphinx document generator to create documentation for one of my apps. When I search for some text that is in the documentation, it appears in the search results page, but the sub-section (----) in which it appears is not displayed in the search results. In examples online, the sub-section does display, e.g.,:

[image: example online that is correct]

For me, only the main section displays:

[image: what I see in my search results page]

Comment: The Sphinx documentation does not use the Alabaster theme. You will either need to switch to a theme that supports that feature or customize the Alabaster theme.

Comment: I see. Thanks, I will give that a try. Do you know of any standard themes that support this feature?

Comment: @StevePiercy actually, i just tested your idea, and I don't think it's right. This website uses alabaster, and I can see sub-sections in the search results. https://alabaster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=alabaster

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Sphinx does not index sub-sections. The example I showed, that has sub-sections in the search results, uses ReadTheDocs.